# VS 2017 .NET Standard Class Library build error when trigger from TFS (VSTS)

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild, .net-core, visual-studio-2017

My sln is built in VS2017 and contains several .Net Standard class library dll. Build always works successfully in my local machine/virtual machine, with VS UI or just use devenv.com via command-line.

But, when I use TFS to create build task, error about InternalVisibleTo shows.

When I use MSBuild,

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\msbuild.exe" "C:\WorkArea\xxxxx\_work\1\s\xxxxx\Main\Source\xxxx.sln" /nologo /nr:false /t:"Clean" /dl:CentralLogger,"C:\WorkArea\xxxxx\tasks\MSBuild\1.0.55\ps_modules\MSBuildHelpers\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.DistributedTask.MSBuild.Logger.dll";"RootDetailId=30268741-631d-4ac8-b4d2-d5b2774b61e7|SolutionDir=C:\WorkArea\xxxxx\_work\1\s\xxxx\Main\Source"*ForwardingLogger,"C:\WorkArea\xxxxx\tasks\MSBuild\1.0.55\ps_modules\MSBuildHelpers\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.DistributedTask.MSBuild.Logger.dll"  /p:platform="Any CPU" /p:configuration="Debug" /p:_MSDeployUserAgent="TFS_6e1df8d0-1a29-425d-803c-d70779d0c76a_build_3175_345868"
```

it has the error:[image]

When I use devenv.com,

`"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\devenv.com" "C:\WorkArea\xxxxxx\_work\1\s\xxxxx\Main\Source\xxxxxx.sln" /build "debug"`

it has the error:

[image]

Is it a known issue or bug of Current Visual Studio 2017 (version 15.2 - 26430.6)? What's wrong with the AssemlyInfo? What's wrong with the TFS build?

Comment: What's the result if you manually build it in local VS2017 on build agent?

Answer (score 3):

You need to restore NuGet packages before attempting the build to resolve references to the reference assemblies that provide you the core types.

You can do this using `msbuild /t:Restore` (TFS/VSTS: use msbuild task) or `nuget.exe restore` (use a nuget.exe >= 4.0.0).

Comment: Perfectly resolved my issue, Thanks! I found  'msbuild /t:Restore' could only restore packages, not directly trigger build. Another msbuild command is needed after that.

Comment: Yes, although `/t:Restore;Build` is possible, it is best to use two invocations or else tool nuget packages that bring build logic won't function properly.

Comment: If it works and was what you are looking for, consider accepting this answer. if not, please let us know.

Answer (score 0):

There must be some issue within the latest Visual Studio 2017. They, the Microsoft, change the project file structure of .Net Core / standard a lot from 2017 RC to current one.